# Can app preferences be read only on startup?

Tags: xcode, settings.bundle, inappsettings

I have implemented [**inappsettings**](http://hg.notalon.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/%5B) to have a preferences view in my application to be able to edit **settings.bundle** values straight in the app.

However now I wanted to read from settings.bundle but reading the [iOS programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html) I found out that settings.bundle should be read on application startup.

So is it not possible to access this preferences any time in my code? Inappsettings would not make any sense if the user could not update preferences any time while the app is running.

Inappsettings offers the method [InAppSettings registerDefaults](http://hg.notalon.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/%5BInAppSettings_registerDefaults)

```
- (void)initialize{
    if([self class] == [AppDelegate class]){
        [InAppSettings registerDefaults];
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if that makes it possible to read preferences any time. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** in my app I have three views, one is the dashboard. The other, a option and a mail view, are shown modally.

In the preferences the user can setup some basic things that I need to send the message. So when the user just started typing and wants to change e.g. the transmission gateway he opens the option view, which is the inappsettings view, and changes some things. I would like to read this changes without restarting the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly Apple wants to impose external preferences UI paradigm on us. Please recall how Mail.app works. Sometimes that paradigm  makes sense, sometimes doesn't. If you have immutable preference set, you don't have to think about events handling onPrefferenceChange, concurrency, synchronization, OS backup and replication issues,etc... However the facilities that Apple provided are very limited in what they can do. You can't even enter an arbitrary string there (Mail.app clearly uses some private API for that). So you have to make a choice whether you can use what Apple offers or implement your own preference system (may be based on top of `NSUSerDefaults` or something). I implemented my own once and I use it ever since. I prefer to have a real in-app preference system. The main advantage of that is to able changing its value without leaving an app.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my question with some details. I thought of synchronization too but since this is a very simple app it would be no problem. Inappsettings gives me a great UI I tried to reproduce that without success.

Comment: I switched form inappsettings to InAppSettingsKit and now I can read user defaults any time.